# How to map topic to a document after topic modeling is done with LDA?

Tags: nlp, gensim, lda

Is there any way I can map generated topic from LDA to the list of documents and identify to which topic it belongs to ? I am interested in clustering documents using unsupervised learning and segregating it into appropriate cluster.

Example, I have 10 topics after running LDA model with the best hyperparameter. So, it should return a number of Topic is already defined withe pre-trained LDA model with new sentence or document that user input.

I am waiting you guys good solution. :)

Ps. I am using Gensim for NLP.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Using Quanteda You can achieve this as follows

```
dtm <- convert(dfmat_news, to = "topicmodels")
lda <- LDA(dtm, k = 10). #10 topics in this case
```

Then you can obtain the most likely topics using the command topics() and save them as a document-level variable.

```
docvars(dfmat_news, 'topic') <- topics(lda)
head(topics(lda), 20)
```

here the tutorial : https://tutorials.quanteda.io/machine-learning/topicmodel/

hope it is clear and useful :)

Comment: This package is written by R. Do you know any other package to use Python? Thanks

Comment: https://www.machinelearningplus.com/nlp/topic-modeling-gensim-python/ look at chapter 18